# My api/login post gets unauthorized on grails 3 with spring-security

Tags: spring, rest, grails, groovy, spring-security

I'm trying to do a Simple Grails RESTFUL API with access_token authorization.

I was following an example as it were on a tutorial, but in this case I can't go on because my localhost:8080/api/login url, the one I should use to get the access_token, does not work.

I first created my grails 3 api like this:

grails create-app --profile rest-api --features hibernate5,json-views,security

These are my Security Domain Classes:

[image]

I did not touch them, they were created by the Spring Security s2-quickstart coopoliova.backend.security User Role command.

This is my application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        //Stateless chain
        [
                pattern: '/**',
                filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
        ],

        //Traditional, stateful chain
        [
                pattern: '/stateful/**',
                filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
        ]
]


// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName =       'coopoliva.backend.security.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName =    'coopoliva.backend.security.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className =                  'coopoliva.backend.security.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/api/rest', access: ['permitAll']]
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS']
]
```

So, I create a couple of users on the bootstrap, like this:

```
def init = { servletContext ->

    def adminUser = new User(username: "adminuser",
            password: "1234", enabled: true);
    adminUser.save(flush:true)

    def userUser = new User(username: "useruser",
            password: "1234", enabled: true);
    userUser.save(flush:true)

    def userRole = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER") ?: new Role("ROLE_USER")
    def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") ?: new Role("ROLE_ADMIN")

    userRole.save(flush:true)
    adminRole.save(flush:true)

    UserRole.create(adminUser, adminRole)
    UserRole.create(userUser, userRole)


}
```

So, theoretically; if I send a POST request with the credentials username: "useruser",password: "1234", it should work.

But, this happens:

[image]

401 UNAUTHORIZED!

So... why is this happening? I just need the access_token so I can pass it through all my other requests.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

These passwords:

```
    def adminUser = new User(username: "adminuser",
            password: "1234", enabled: true);
    adminUser.save(flush:true)

    def userUser = new User(username: "useruser",
            password: "1234", enabled: true);
    userUser.save(flush:true)
```

Are not password encripted by spring security service, and thus, wont be correct when logging in:

This is the correct way to add users:

```
    def adminUser = new User(username: "adminuser",
            password: springSecurityService.encodePassword("1234"), enabled: true);
    adminUser.save(flush:true)

    def userUser = new User(username: "useruser",
            password: springSecurityService.encodePassword("1234"), enabled: true);
    userUser.save(flush:true)
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to permit access to your login url

```
[pattern: 'api/login/**', access: ['permitAll']]
```

Also, you have duplicate configuration for grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap

Comment: I think @sudhir is the right answer you can check this repo is from Alvaro Sanchez and it use spring security rest https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-angular-springsecurity-gr8days-warsaw

Comment: I tried both things, but its the same... I added         [pattern: '/api/**',         access: ['permitAll']] on staticRules, and         [pattern: '/api/**',       filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS'] on chainMap, no success.